# Cannot get all my ethernet ports detected/connected

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet

I'm trying to make connections through my 3 ethernet ports but for some reason my ubuntu can only detect 2 although there is a wired connection in the third port as well.

Below is the result of `ifconfig`:

[image]

This is the connection from the machine:

[image]

Comment: Look like an ILO port, you can’t use it from host. (And not related to lo0)

Comment: @Archemar so this means my machine supports only two ethernet connections?

Comment: Does `ifconfig -a` reveal an additional interface? If not, I agree with @Archemar, it could be an iLO interface. The loopback (`lo`) device has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @eblock Yes only these two and lo

Comment: Then the one you point as "not working" is an ILO, this a special network that enable you to power off/power on device, mount ISO image, and access console (handy for fsck and reset root passwd). What does label say ?

Comment: Show us the symbol of that port that the red arrow is hiding.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc7pV.jpg

Comment: @Archemar https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc7pV.jpg

Comment: The symbol is of a regular ethernet interface....ILO normally has a spanner sign. Show us your `lspci` output, and the output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro here is the output of `lspci` http://pasteall.org/1477915

Comment: Interestingly enough it does not appear. How about `ifconfig -a` does it show it? If not, check in the BIOS if it is disabled.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it gives the exact same output of ifconfig shown in my question

Comment: so have you checked the BIOS setup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89238/discussion-between-tak-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm not sure exactly what to check?could you please advise?

Comment: I am at work and not interested in providing general computer helpdesk, sorry.

Comment: Can you tell us the model of the enclosure and motherboard? It's possible that some motherboards use that port for IPMI and some use it as a third ordinary NIC. The Supermicro enclosure manual I looked at didn't say.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the model is supermicro 7049

Comment: Is it [this](https://www.supermicro.com/a_images/products/views/7049GP-TRT_rear.jpg)? Then you have two general purpose NICs and an IPNI NIC.

Comment: You'll probably get a more complete answer over on https://superuser.com, which covers hardware and software, and they're likely familiar with Supermicro servers. Your question was about Unix, but the answer turns out to be more about server hardware.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick so this means I only have two ethernet ports, right?

Comment: @Tak Yes. The third is only to manage the system. With that one, you can do things like power the system on and off, access the console remotely, etc.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks and Is it possible to have an extra ethernet port somehow?

Comment: I read Supermicro's IPMI manual, and it doesn't show a way to make that NIC visible to the operating system. I think you'll have to add additional hardware to your system, such a PCIE card with Ethernet ports.